# google api returns zero results

Tags: google-plus

I am attempting to pull Google+ activity data for a public page via the API, yet it returns zero items despite there being many public posts on the profile. Any idea what might be wrong?

Profile Link:
https://plus.google.com/107276257619752352564/posts

API Explorer Link:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=114637566932717330174&collection=public&_h=2&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile user ID that you provided (107276257619752352564) doesn't match the one you're using in the explorer (114637566932717330174). Executing it with the profile user ID and making sure you've authorized the request appears to return results:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=107276257619752352564&collection=public&_h=2&

Comment: Oh, snap. I didn't catch that. I was using the profile ID that we had stored in our system. Looks like they changed it at some point. Thanks for noticing that. Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes.

Comment: So, if you use the ID that I had used in the explorer in the URL path, it appears to redirect to the CORRECT profile, what would cause one ID to redirect to another?  URL with incorrect ID,https://plus.google.com/114637566932717330174/posts. URL with correct ID, https://plus.google.com/107276257619752352564/posts